# http to https redirection based on subdomain name

Tags: apache, http, ssl, https

We have 3 sub domains pointed to a apache webserver,all the subdomains are for different web applications, we have got ssl against the sub domains,ssl certificates were installed, but we are not able to redirect the http requests to https.. we have to write manually https://subdomain.domain-name.com to access our applications...

We are using zend server 6 . please help us to know so that all the http request can be redirected to  https.

we have written this on our httpd.conf file

```
    RewriteEngine On
     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*?)\.domain-name.com$
      RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
        RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST} [nc]
```

we are really new to this.we will be highly grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Create .htaccess file on http://subdomain.domain-name.com and put this code in that

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^$ https://subdomain.domain-name.com [L,R=302]
```

Comment: but we have 3 subdomains and where should we write this please help!!

Comment: domain-name.com is some where else  and this server is presently having 3 subdomain pointed towards it . we dont have any .htaccess file  and do we have to write RewriteRule for all this subdomains .